# Can't write to OpenLDAP: "shadow context; no update referral"

Tags: openldap, deleting

I just set up an OpenLDAP server (v2.4.23) and loaded some data. I can browse and edit via Apache Directory Studio, but not deletions all fail.

For example, I tried to delete a list of DNs from a file:

```
ldapdelete -f rmroles.txt -W -D "cn=admin,cn=config"
```

but it dies with the message:

```
ldap_delete: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: shadow context; no update referral
```

Most of the info I've found suggests that this is related to replication, but I *haven't* set up replication on this server yet. `olcReadOnly` is `FALSE`, and I've set olcAccess to `to * by * manage`.

Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently just having the `olcMirrorMode` attribute present on `cn=config` (even when set to `FALSE`) is enough to trigger shadow context. Delete the attribute and restart slapd.

Comment: Another contribution: I was defining olcMirrorMode on a separate "changetype: modify" in the end of the .ldif file. It does not seem to be a good idea. When I added the olcMirrorMode as part of the previous "changetype: modify" I as doing, it ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I found that my solution was slightly different.

Again, my LDAP server was in a sync/replication setup and needed to be disabled.

In `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` the `syncrepl` directive was specified (and some associated configuration underneath).

Commenting this out and restarting the ldap server allowed me to make changes to the LDAP database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just watch attribute userPassword's value.
2. It is prefixed by {MD5} (in my case)
3. Just select Encryption method according to it